Sphinx RTD Theme improperly nesting subheadings
I have a single index.rst file that has the contents of my README.rst included using the .. include:: directive. When rendering this using make latexpdf or using the .. contents:: directive in html, the TOC is rendered properly as the following:
Description
Installation
  - From PyPI
  - From GitHub
Usage
Implementation

The properly formatted pdf output's TOC

When running make html using sphinx-rtd-theme, however, this is rendered as follows:
   Description
[+]Installation
   From PyPI
   From GitHub
   Usage
   Implementation

The improperly formatted sidebar

I’ve tried adjusting :maxdepth: / max_depth in both the .. toctree:: directive and in conf.py.html_theme_options respectively. Neither of these seemed to make any difference, nor did :titlesonly:, collapse_navigation, or :numbered:. I’m unsure if this is a Sphinx issue or a theme issue. I’ve even split the .. include:: directive as below to make the index.rst more in-line with traditional Sphinx index.rst structure, but this also made no difference.
.. include:: ../../README.rst
   :end-line: 3

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 3
   :caption: Contents:


.. include:: ../../README.rst
   :start-line: 4

I've also tested the style_nav_header_background theme option to confirm html_theme_options are being used (they are). I attempted to test with the default Alabaster theme, but Alabaster didn't want to generate any sidebar navigation at all, even with the proper sidebars included. Finally, I installed and ran rstcheck to confirm that my rst is valid and it detected no errors for README.rst. That being said, when scanning index.rst, it threw the following AttributeError:
WARNING:rstcheck_core.checker:An `AttributeError` error occured. This is most probably due to a code block directive (code/code-block/sourcecode) without a specified language. This may result in a false negative for source: 'docs/source/index.rst'. The reason can also be another directive. For more information see the FAQ (https://rstcheck-core.rtfd.io/en/latest/faq) or the corresponding github issue: https://github.com/rstcheck/rstcheck-core/issues/3.
Success! No issues detected.

Here's a relevant snippet of README.rst for reference:
################
django-npi-field
################

Description
===========
**Django-npi-field** is a Django library which validates and stores 10-digit U.S. `National Provider Identifier (NPI)`_
numbers.

.. _`National Provider Identifier (NPI)`: \
   https://www.cms.gov/Regulations-and-Guidance/Administrative-Simplification/NationalProvIdentStand

Installation
============
From PyPI
---------
Using pip:

.. code-block:: zsh

   pip install django-npi-field


You might add this to their long backlog, https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme/issues But honestly switching to another popular theme might save you more time.

Did you try a combination of both collapse_navigation=True and navigation_depth=2 or greater? See doc ref: https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuring.html#confval-collapse_navigation

I didn't do collapse_navigation = True as the docs seemed to indicate that this is set True by default. navigation_depth has primarily been set to 3. Setting it higher or lower didn't appear to have nay effect on the rendering.

So this appears to be an issue specifically with the sphinx-rtd-theme, not with Sphinx itself. On Lex’s recommendation in the comments, I switched from the RTD theme to the Groundwork theme and it rendered flawlessly. If you’re having the same issue, I recommend going to sphinx-themes.org and seeing if there is another theme that fits your preferred style and works properly.
